# OpenMP with Eigen Matrix operation in C++ MEX

Tags: c++, matlab, openmp, mex, eigen3

I would like to compute the diagonal elements of B'*Q^(-1)*B for N-by-n dense matrix B and N-by-N sparse matrix Q, where N is about 10^6 and n is about 10^5. I tried to use OpenMP to compute the diagonal elements using the following Mex code. However, the timing for for the code with OpenMP and without OpenMP is almost the same. I think I did not effectively enable the OpenMP feature in my code. When I run the test, I used 28 cores.

I am new to OpenMP. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thank you very much!

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include <Eigen>
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <omp.h>


typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,Eigen::ColMajor,std::make_signed<mwIndex>::type> MatlabSparse;

Eigen::Map<MatlabSparse > matlab_to_eigen_sparse(const mxArray * mat)
{
    mxAssert(mxGetClassID(mat) == mxDOUBLE_CLASS,
    "Type of the input matrix isn't double");
    mwSize     m = mxGetM(mat);
    mwSize     n = mxGetN(mat);
    mwSize    nz = mxGetNzmax(mat);
    /*Theoretically fails in very very large matrices*/
    mxAssert(nz <= std::numeric_limits< std::make_signed<mwIndex>::type>::max(),
    "Unsupported Data size.");
    double  * pr = mxGetPr(mat);
    MatlabSparse::StorageIndex* ir = reinterpret_cast<MatlabSparse::StorageIndex*>(mxGetIr (mat));
    MatlabSparse::StorageIndex* jc = reinterpret_cast<MatlabSparse::StorageIndex*>(mxGetJc (mat));
    Eigen::Map<MatlabSparse> result(m, n, nz, jc, ir, pr);
    return result;
}



void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

    // prhs[0]: Q
    Eigen::Map<MatlabSparse> Q = matlab_to_eigen_sparse(prhs[0]);
    mwSize N = mxGetM(prhs[0]); // size of BAUs for constructing the GGM

    // prhs[1]: B (dense matrix)
    mwSize n = mxGetN(prhs[1]);
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> B(mxGetPr(prhs[1]), N, n);



     Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > Qsolver;
     Qsolver.analyzePattern(Q);
     Qsolver.factorize(Q);  



    // intermidiate variables
    Eigen::VectorXd Qb(N), xsol(n);
    mwIndex i;
    //mexPrintf("\n begin for-loop.\n");

    // compute diagonal elements of B'*Q^(-1)*B
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, Qb)
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        Qb = Qsolver.solve(B.col(i));
        xsol(i) = B.col(i).dot(Qb);
    }

    //mexPrintf("\n finish for-loop.\n");

    double* x = (double*) mxCalloc(n, sizeof(double));
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(x, n, 1) = xsol;

    // set output
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, 1, mxREAL);
    mxSetPr(plhs[0], x);

}
```

Comment: How did you compile? OpenMP requires a compiler flag.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I used the following command to compile the mex code in matlab: `mex -v CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -fwrapv -DNDEBUG" test_mp.cpp -I/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen CxxFLAGS="$CxxFLAGS -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -fopenmp"`. The mex code is compiled correctly with OpenMP flags.

Comment: Does the loop take a large chunk of total execution time? You might have false sharing at `xsol(i)=...`, when different threads write to the same cache line, all threads need to refresh it. Consider adding a line `mexPrintf ("num_thds=%d\n", omp_get_num_threads());` inside the parallel section to see if you get threads spawned (you can separate `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp for` for this).

Comment: What are the values of `n` and `N`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: In my test example, I set `N=1,260,864, n=100`, which took about 25 seconds for the serial code and the code with `OpenMP`. These two versions of code give the same results, since I checked their outputs in MATLAB. When I used the following code, it outputs just 1 core, but I used 28 cores in my test. `#pragma omp parallel private(i, Qb)
    {
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            mexPrintf ("num_thds=%d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
            Qb = Qsolver.solve(B.col(i));
            xsol(i) = B.col(i).dot(Qb);
        }
    }`

Comment: @CrisLuengo: When you mentioned `xsol(i)=...`, do you mean I need to allocate allocate or define the variable `xsol` inside the `#pragma omp parallel` region?

Comment: Unrelated: You can exploit the symmetry in `Q=P'*L*L'*P` and just calculate `Qb = Qsolver.permutationP() * B.col(i); Qsolver.matrixL().solveInPlace(Qb); xsol(i) = Qb.squaredNorm();` (You may need to check `Qsolver.permutationP().size()>0`, perhaps).

Comment: @chtz: Thank you very much for pointing this out. It gives me 35% of speedup.